# In MySQL, how can I use a single row from a joined table to filter out unwanted dates in a GROUP_CONCAT?

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join, outer-join

I have a `loan` table and a `loan_status` table.  The `loan` table includes, amongst other columns, a `loan_id` and a `date_issued` column.  Here I have a query that gets the `date_issued` for the **OTHER** loans:

```
(select GROUP_CONCAT(Date(lj.date_issued) SEPARATOR ', ') from loan lj INNER JOIN client clj ON (clj.client_id = lj.client_id) 

where clj.client_id = '2299629' and lj.id != l.id) as other_loan_issue_dates,
```

Since there are 7 loans for this client, I have a table like this, with 6 comma separated dates:

[image]

**THE PROBLEM:**

I need to exclude from the `other_loan_issue_dates` any `loan` that has a `status_id` of `27` in the `loan_status` table AND that `status_id` was the last entry in the `loan_status` table for that `loan`.  Each loan has many statuses.

Here is an example:

[image]

This query displays a `test` column that determines whether it should be filtered out in `other_loan_issue_dates`:

```
select status_id = 27 as test from loan_status ls where loan_id = 2052456 ORDER BY datestamp DESC LIMIT 1;
```

The following is wrong and doesn't finish running:

```
(select GROUP_CONCAT(Date(lj.date_issued) SEPARATOR ', ') from loan lj INNER JOIN client clj ON (clj.client_id = lj.client_id) 

JOIN loan_status ls ON ls.status_id = (
select status_id from loan_status ls where loan_id = 2052456 ORDER BY datestamp DESC LIMIT 1
)

where clj.client_id = '2299629' and lj.id != l.id and ls.status_id != 27) as other_loan_issue_dates,
```

I also tried the following but I don't know if it works because it seems to multiply the result:

```
(select GROUP_CONCAT(Date(lj.date_issued) SEPARATOR ', ') from loan lj INNER JOIN client clj ON (clj.client_id = lj.client_id) 

LEFT OUTER JOIN loan_status ls ON (ls.loan_id = lj.id)

where clj.client_id = '2299629' and lj.id != l.id and (select status_id = 27 as test from loan_status ls where loan_id = ls.loan_id ORDER BY datestamp DESC LIMIT 1) = 0) as other_loan_issue_dates,
```

How can I use the last `loan_status` row, check if it's `status_id` is `27` and if so, exclude that `loan`?

Comment: Maybe you could just add something like "loan_id NOT IN (SELECT loan_id from loan_status WHERE status_id = 27)" in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm getting your queries right, because there are just parts of some bigger queries. However, I would recommend you to try something like this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Date(lj.date_issued) SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM loan lj
INNER JOIN client clj ON (clj.client_id = lj.client_id) 
WHERE clj.client_id = '2299629'
AND lj.id != l.id
AND lj.loan_id NOT IN (SELECT loan_id from loan_status WHERE status_id = 27)
```

The `SELECT loan_id from loan_status WHERE status_id = 27` would give you the ids of loans that have `status_id=27`. You then put `NOT IN` to tell MySQL to exclude such loans.

Comment: @IIdar Akhmetov Thanks.  I get `Unknown column 'lj.loan_id' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'` right now but I will try and adapt your answer!

Comment: @DaveChambers yeah, you got the idea, just make sure that the column/table names are correct.

Comment: @DaveChambers and please do not forget to accept the answer if the solution works :)

Comment: @IIdar Akhmetov Please accept my edit to your answer as only then does it solve the issue.

Comment: @DaveChambers Moderators declined your edit, so it's probably better to edit the original post (using "EDITED"), or post it as a comment.